# What are the different types of digital signals, other than binary?

Tags: digital-logic, terminology

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81777/can-a-digital-signal-has-3-three-values1-0-and-1

Above is link to a my related question, especially relevance in the answer from Hilmar, but that does not answer in detail this subject question.

As Hilmar said,

> Binary refers to a signal that has only two amplitude values. So a binary signal is a subset of digital signals.

That means there are also other signals in set of digital signals.

What are some of those common/popular signals types beside binary signals? What about integer numbers, are they also considered digital?

Comment: the thing you cite gives you an example. It also gives you a definition that you can apply to your example "decimal numbers". So, do that! Without you explaining exactly what you've done and where you've got stuck doing things yourself, this question is simply too broad.

Comment: A decimal number can have as many digits after the decimal point as you wish and therefore, at the limit can be regarded as an analogue number. Maybe you were thinking "integers"?

Comment: If you are talking about hardware electronics, almost all digital implementations use binary. But decimal (with 10 signals per digit, or a more compact form with 4 signals per digit), were used in the past, and are are still marginally used (e.g. simple digital clocks). But you can argue that those type of implementations are still binary because each signal still has only two possible values. And in software, working with digital signals with any arbitrary bounds is possible, and commonplace. So, where do you draw the line? What do you mean by "digital signal" exactly?

Comment: @dim "digital signal exactly": well, that's just asking engr the same as I did: to take the definition they link to, and apply it!

Comment: @MarcusMüller The definition of "digital signal" from the link is not enough to guess what OP is talking about. Take a number from 0-99 encoded in BCD, for example: you can apply this definition to the entire number (0-99), to a single digit (0-9), or to a single binary bit part of the combination used to describe a digit value (0-1). Depending on what you choose, the answer is "there's only binary in digital electronics", or "digital can sometimes use decimal", or "digital is whatever number you want". What's missing isn't the definition of "digital". It's the definition of "signal".

Comment: Well said! Also, a bit of what I discussed with Justme under their answer :)

Comment: "Binary refers to a signal that has only two amplitude values." ... doesn't that sentence imply the possibility of extension to other forms of digital signal? Examples? Anything I can count on my fingers is literally digital.

Answer (score 0):

Anything quantized to arbitrary amount of discrete values or symbols that can be represented in digital fashion, such as numbers. For example in digital computers symbols are digital numbers encoded in binary.

It does not matter if the symbol that is represented by a number has some special base to interpret it, like binary, decimal, octal, hexadecimal, etc, as a digital computer can internally work with words, or symbols that consists of multiple bits.

1-bit symbols numbers are binary with 2 values.

8-bit symbols are bytes with 256 values.

Audio can be 16, 24 or floating point numbers. All these are symbols that are just multi-bit numbers so thus digital in a digital computer.

Comment: note that *numbers* are not the same as *signals*. A signal that can be represented by discrete values (discrete is the important part – numbers can also be real) isn't already digital, it also needs to be defined only at discrete points. A number can't be digital  – it's just a value. A signal can be digital; it's different values at different times.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Good comment. A signal could be a sequence of numbers, for example digital audio is a discrete time digital signal.

Comment: exactly! It can also be a series of playing cards, or unicode characters, or of pixels in an image (as long as these pixels only take discrete values).

Comment: Wouldn't "values" be a better term to use than "level"?  As in "8-bit symbols are bytes that can represent 256 values".  This would keep the distinction between the voltage levels that represent each bit and the value that multiple bits represent?

Answer (score 0):

Digital electronics signals are just that: they signal information using digital electronics, carrying that information from a source to a destination.

By far the most common information signalled is binary data.

That's when a digital signal LOW represents binary 0 and a digital signal HIGH represents binary 1.

Binary can represent numbers larger than 1 using multiple binary digits (bits). So these must be signalled using multiple wires, one for each bit.

Once you understand how data is represented in binary numbers then how that data is carried by digital electronics signals is straightforward. Research and read up on how signed, unsigned, fixed-point and floating-point numbers and also ASCII are represented in a binary format. It's far too much to explain on this website.

Digital electronics signalling can use other levels to binary HIGH and LOW, such as tri-state which is for electronic convenience to save on IC pins and PCB tracks. It acts like disconnecting a logic gate output from a signal, allowing multiple gates to drive the same tracks at different times. MPU/MCU data buses the most common example.

Incidentally, there are other digital electronics schemes for signalling more than two levels on one wire. But they're in the minority, by electronics usage, and it would muddy the explanation of the basics to start wading into that.

Comment: this isn't conforming to the canonical definition of "digital": whether something is digital or not doesn't depend on the electronics that deal with it, at all. All that matters is that both 1. values and 2. times are from a discrete set.

Comment: Also, outside of digital logic within one device, digital signals with more than two states are super common: PAM-4 even in ancient Ethernet, and let's not talk about the constellations used in wireless and optical communications, DSL, or telephone line modems since the 1970s. So, I'd sadly argue this answer is a bit misleading!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I knew there'd a be a wave on its way here :-) Digital signals carrying binary dominate in the billions of gates in our phones and PCs, with only miniscule% carrying non-binary for comms. Besides that, it's intended to be an eye-opening and practical engineering explanation as basis for further learning, rather than a drier scientific definition on it. It's all on digital electronics, not digital signalling, which I'll make clearer and hopefully that and these explanations will remove the downvote. Thanks.

Comment: hey, but it's still misleading: nothing says you need to represent non-binary values as combination of binaries; I'd argue you bringing that in is what muddies the waters here, which (admittedly, different background, but based on the material OP refers to!) is clear cut: Signal values from discrete set, signal points from discrete set: Then, and only then, signal digital. Binary isn't sufficient without the time / sample point aspect, and also not necessary. And OP is explicitly asking about non-binary!

Comment: I do agree, however, this is a pretty good representation of what it means for *electronics* to be *digital electronics*. But it's not really describing the signal side - it describes the "how does the electronics that typically do digital stuff" side. :)

Comment: Actually @MarcusMüller, now I look it at, I've answered the second half of the OP's question (*What about decimal numbers? Are they also considered digital?*) entirely and ignored the first half (*That means there are also other signals in set of digital signals, what are some of those common/popular signals types beside binary signals?*), which is the bulk of the question and the point you're rightly making. Ahh, and it was all going so well... Ran out of time now but will either correct it or delete it.

Comment: Don't delete it!

Comment: a) I like it. b) It's just a special focus. Honestly, OP's question wasn't well-focused to begin with (as they literally ask for an example, which was already given in their textbook, and it's really mostly about applying a definition to something!), so you took the part that you considered (or... unconsciously considered) to be the one most important to answer.

Comment: Note that ~45 years ago, Intel had a PROM that internally used ternary logic to store information.  The voltage levels IIRC were 0 V, +2.5 V, and +5 V, approximately.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, binary represents two. When it comes to digital signals, they are signals that represent data as a sequence. Digital signals convey discrete symbols that are usually interpreted as digits. Most digital signals are binary or logic (signals,) which are later represented by two voltage band, for examplr 0 and 1, whereby one is near a reference value and the other a value near the supply voltage. (Must be in physical state).

The term binary emphasize the use of finite numbers to communicate signals.